# How can I run DMR Topic Model using MALLET Java API?

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, lda, topic-modeling

I have two dataset text.txt and another metadata.txt. I formatted the data one document per line. I would like to use MALLET Java Api for DMR Topic Model. However, I am not able to do so. I am totally new to Java and this kind of complex modeling. Also, I do not have any prior knowledge on the topic modeling. I am looking for expertise knowledge here. Could you please help me with this?